# How to make a factory class extensible?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I'm designing a simple application that uses the factory design pattern. I'm following ->[this](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/08/factory-pattern-design-patterns-in-javaj2ee/)<- example. What I'm wondering is how do I make the factory class extensible? In the example given one would have to modify the factory class code if he wanted to add a Mac button. How can I make it so that this is not necessary?

Is there a way to extend the factory class'functionality that does not override its original method thereby losing that functionality? Or maybe there's a way to make object creation fully dynamic (using overloaded methods?) so that the factory class does not need to rely on conditional statements?

Comment: Are you making an abstract factory? Or just a concrete factory? Some say that the concrete is not a true design pattern, that for flexibility of a design pattern, it needs to be abstract.

Comment: That's likely your problem. Have you gone through a book on design patterns including the abstract factory pattern? If not, I suggest you do so.

Comment: For more on this, please look at this Wikipedia article on the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

The answer would depend what the factory is doing but in the example provided, you could do this:

```
package tips.pattern.factory;
public class ButtonFactory {

    private final Map<String, Button> osToButton;

    public ButtonFactory(Map<String, Button> osToButton) {
        this.osToButton = osToButton;
    } 

    public Button createButton(String os){
        return this.osToButton.get(os);
    }
}
```